# Google Sheets Auto-Parses Strings To Dates...Sometimes?

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using Google Sheets to scrape stock data from the tables on Yahoo Finance. For example, to grab a company's P/E Ratio, it's as simple as:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DELL","table", 2),3,2)
```

However, I'm running into an odd behavior when grabbing the earnings date. Yahoo Finance lists them in two possible formats: like "Feb 25, 2021" or like "Jan 28, 2021 - Feb 01, 2021"

In the first case, just grab the cell value exactly like above:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DELL","table", 2),5,2)
```

In the second, grab the cell value then parse out the first bit:

```
=LEFT(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/KO","table", 2),5,2),12)
```

Now for the issue: it's inconsistent with how it treats the data.  In the first case, it recognizes that the string "looks like" a date, & returns it directly as an actual date - as if the call were wrapped in `DATEVALUE()`, though obviously it is not.  In the latter case, it returns it as a string, so you need to explicitly wrap it in `DATEVALUE()`.

Why does it behave inconsistently, returning the first string as a date but the second string as a string?  This makes it difficult to have one formula that handles both cases, as `DATEVALUE()` will break if you pass it something that's already a date (i.e. as in the first case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use your `LEFT` formula in both cases, add in the end `*1` and format both as `Date`**, for a single, consistent formula.

`KO` example

```
=LEFT(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/KO","table", 2),5,2),12)*1
```

`DELL` example

```
=LEFT(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DELL","table", 2),5,2),12)*1
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like adding *1 was the key that fixed it, thanks.  Very strange that it doesn't behave consistently in terms of auto-parsing some strings to dates but not others...but *1 fixes it & makes it consistent :)